# How reverse sort on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to reverse this sort on click using ReactJS:

```
        if (this.state.Prz==3) {
        this.props.files.sort(function(a,b){
            return a.lastModified < b.lastModified ? 1 : -1;
        });
    }
```

I tried many tricks searching on Google but I'm still stuck.

Comment: Seems okay to me.

Comment: How should the sort order be determined? Does it come from the state, or the props, or what? It seems like you just need to put a condition inside the sort function.

Comment: sort is determined by the props. I add condition it's work better, but seems my _lasModified_ is wrong but it help a lot, thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can change the direction of sort (since you seem to be sorting by `Date`) by swapping `1` and `-1`:

```
this.props.files.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.lastModified < b.lastModified ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Or you can reverse the array, assuming it was sorted before doing that (`concat()` is for making a copy of the array, keeping things "immutable"):

```
this.props.files.concat().reverse();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse an array simply by calling reverse

```
this.props.files.reverse()
```

Beware though that this will mutate the original array.

Answer (score 0):

Here finally how I did. I add a condition.

```
    if (this.state.activePrz==3) {
        this.props.files.sort(function(a,b){
            var asc = a.lastModified < b.lastModified;
            var desc = a.lastModified > b.lastModified;
            if(asc == true){
                return asc;
            }else{
                return desc;
            }
        })
    }
```

And it works.

I couldn't :

```
this.props.files.reverse();
```

or

```
this.props.files.concat().reverse();
```

The error message was :

> Cannot read property 'files' of undefined

Many thanks for your help.